# How to action a form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, character, action

I'm new in this domain so please excuse me if I don't speak technically correct.
I have a form  with a red border. When I enter a character in the form, the red border has to disappear. How can I do this in JavaScript?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you provide a sample of your code, it would be easier to make a solution suggestion and much easier for you to implement afterwards :)

Comment: My code is: freetexthost.com/0r2io53yzm . Also I have a css with this code: input{border: 1px solid red;}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
       
        event.preventDefault();
    });

$('input').on('keyup',function(){
    
    if($(this).val() === ""){
      $(this).addClass('error');   
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('error');
    }

});
});
```

```css
.error {
   border-color: red;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label> Your Name:
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter name"/>
        
    </label>
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. Hope to know how to integrate it in my project.

Comment: @ionut if its helpful mark this as answer and upvote.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I don't know how to manage it. My code is: http://freetexthost.com/0r2io53yzm . Also I have a css with this code: input{border: 1px solid red;}. Could you please help me somehow?